# pandas.test() (version 0.18) FAILS after fresh anaconda install

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda, nose

I have just installed Anaconda 4.0 on a windows 64 machine, and ran `pandas.test()`.

Important thing: my computer is behind a firewall so no test can access the internet. Still I am getting a lot of failures.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.test('fast')

...

Ran 9444 tests in 474.070s

FAILED (SKIP=147, errors=10, failures=18)
```

I understand that some tests that need internet access would fail, but what about

```
FAIL: test_categorical_series_repr_timedelta_ordered (pandas.tests.test_categorical.TestCategoricalAsBlock)

FAIL: test_categorical_series_repr_timedelta (pandas.tests.test_categorical.TestCategoricalAsBlock)
```

What should I do? Any help appreciated!

Comment: I ran the tests on a mac with python 3.4 anaconda 4 freshly updated and got: E=0, F=16, S=119... I guess this is a question for pandas mailing list...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its a temporary bug (see pandas mailing list). everything should be fixed in Pandas 0.18.1